# Set the same width of a “Position: fixed” div as parent div(flexbox item)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can Ｉ make the same width of the NavWrapper as parent?

I want these links at a fixed position even the main section overflows.

I know how to do this without Flex. Is there any pure CSS way to do that?

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
nav { 
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  background: gray;
}
.nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-wrapper a {
  flex: 1 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
section {
  flex: 5 1 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
         <a href="#">Home</a> 
         <a href="#">About</a> 
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `fixed` position- you can see why I say this after looking at the example below:

Remove the `fixed` positioning and add `height: 100vh` to `nav`:

```
nav {
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  background: gray;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Now wrap the contents on a section into an `inner` div that is positioned `absolute` like this:

```
section {
  flex: 5 1 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This will allow the `section` to remain at `100vh` of the `nav-wrapper` and the extra height will overflow.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
nav {
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  background: gray;
  height: 100vh;
}
.nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.nav-wrapper a {
  flex: 1 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
section {
  flex: 5 1 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#">Home</a> 
      <a href="#">About</a> 
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Lorem</p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae molestiae, libero inventore nobis et veritatis, laborum vitae, vel eaque omnis ad adipisci quia velit blanditiis qui. Cum voluptas quisquam itaque possimus accusamus repellendus quia iure
      asperiores. Unde, rerum nihil maiores nisi, iusto voluptate id cumque incidunt, perspiciatis facilis perferendis explicabo.       
      <p>Lorem</p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae molestiae, libero inventore nobis et veritatis, laborum vitae, vel eaque omnis ad adipisci quia velit blanditiis qui. Cum voluptas quisquam itaque possimus accusamus repellendus quia iure
      asperiores. Unde, rerum nihil maiores nisi, iusto voluptate id cumque incidunt, perspiciatis facilis perferendis explicabo.       
      <p>Lorem</p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae molestiae, libero inventore nobis et veritatis, laborum vitae, vel eaque omnis ad adipisci quia velit blanditiis qui. Cum voluptas quisquam itaque possimus accusamus repellendus quia iure
      asperiores. Unde, rerum nihil maiores nisi, iusto voluptate id cumque incidunt, perspiciatis facilis perferendis explicabo.       
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Check this out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Hi kukkuz, thanks for you help. But there is a problem that when the windows size becomes small, there will be two scroll bar.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjjGgE

Comment: What I acctually want to do is to implement the layout like this site [Jianshu](http://www.jianshu.com) using flex.

Comment: two scroll bars because the nav is overflowing... remove it by specifying `overflow: auto` for the `nav`...

Comment: "Jianshu" has `overflow: hidden` for the nav I guess... so I guess your queries are answered?

Comment: I tried to add 'overflow:hidden' to the wrapper and it works.. But is there a way to remove the blank space at the right side of the scrollbar?

Comment: that is some issue with *codepen* code I guess because when I do "Tidy HTML" in the HTML tag you don't have the blank space issue...

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helps. I will mark this as the answer.